# accessing serialized cookies in with ngCookie

Tags: angularjs, cookies

am trying to access a key in serial cookie object using ngCookie but keep getting undefined, any idea please?

```
here is how the cookie object look in the browser:
j%3A%7B%22item1%22%3A%22Jane%20Doe%22%2C%22item2%22%3A%22cynthiamoris%22%2C%22dp%22%3A%22mode.jpg%22%7D
```

Comment: please, type the code you are running

Comment: .controller('MessagesCtrl', ['MessageService', '$routeParams', 'socket', '$window', '$cookies', function (MessageService, $routeParams, socket, $window, $cookies) {
      var self = this

      self.send = function ($event) {
        var m = {msg: this.msg, me: false}
        var key = $event.which || $event.keyCode
        if (key === 13) {
          self.messages.push(m)

          $window.alert($cookies.get('user.item1'))
        }
      }

Comment: What do you get if you alert `$cookies.get("user")`?

Answer (score 0):

man, i saw this.

> $cookies.get('user.item1');

So, i think `user` is the object where you are getting the cookie. I know that `$cookies.get(string)`, but you are typing an object. I guess the cookie is in `item1`. So, just call the property.

> $cookies.get(user.item1);

Comment: if i tried using $cookies.get('user.item1') i get undefined. and if i use $cookies.get('user') i get this: j:{"item1":"jane" Moris","item2":"cynthiamoris","dpurl":"mode.jpg"} the j: object is not part of the original object

Comment: Don't use `'user.item1'` because you are declaring `user.item1` as a string and not as an object. do you know what is the property who contains the cookie??

Comment: yes, the name of the cookie object is user which contains three item which are serialized.  so i wan to know to parse or deserialized the cookie object into the original plane objec

Comment: Ok. so. if `user` is the name of the cookie, I'd guess that `var user = j%3A%7B%22item1%22%3A%22Jane%20Doe%22%2C%22item2%22%3A%22cynthiamoris%22%2C%22dp%22%3A%22mode.jpg%22%7D`, in that case, the answer is the code you typed before `$cookies.get(user)` but without the `''` for the same reason that i explained